# Spring AMQP, catch listener container stopped event

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

Using springframework 4.3.6, I have configured AMQP (RabbitMQ) to retry connection to the message broker every 5 seconds for 5 times. When all attempts fail to make a connection to the broker, spring fails with a warning:

```
WARN  [x.x.x.x.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] stopping container - restart recovery attempts exhausted
```

I would like to listen to the listener container stop event and notify systems team about unavailability of the message bus.

I tried creating ApplicationListener with type ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent and also DeclarationExceptionEvent. But none of it worked. So i was wondering if there is any other way to catch container stopped event in case of failure to start the container successfully.

If it helps, the error message i get after each attempt to connect is

```
ERROR [x.x.x.x.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
```